# Is it possible to have "Omitempty" json tag as default behaviour?

Tags: json, go, encoding

I want to omitempty **always** without having to write `json:",omitempty"` everywhere. Is this possible by some config of encoding/json?

Comment: See the [Encoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder) documentation for available options.  Making ",omitempty" the default is not one of the options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this possible by some config of encoding/json?

No.

But you could implement your encoder via the [JSON marshaling interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler):

```
type Marshaler interface {
    MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
}
```

However, without forking the current standard library implementation, this would entail a *lot* of work, for relatively little gains.